# Vuetify expansion panel with draggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am newbie to Vuejs and vuetify and also stackoverflow. I got the task to make a draggable expansion panel in vuetify. I tried a lot but nothing worked out for me. Here are the some fiddles and github source code which i followed:

1.) https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

2.) Functionnal Vuejs 2 sortable v-expansion-panels - google search please

But nothing worked out for me. Can somebody help me out with this? Any fiddles or codepen that i can refer to?

I can't import a component as using this vuetify and vue.js through cdn only.

Thanks for the help in advance.

HTML (Prototype):

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
        v-bind:headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
        ref="sortableTable"
      >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr class="sortableRow" :key="itemKey(props.item)"> <!-- NOTE:  You'll need a unique ID, that is specific to the given item, for the key.   Not providing a unique key that's bound to the item object will break drag and drop sorting.  The itemKey method will return a uid for a given object using WeakMap.  You could just use a property in the object with a unique value, like "props.item.name" in this case, but often getting a unique value from the object's properties can be difficult, like when adding new rows, or when the unique field is open to editing, etc. -->
          <td class="px-1" style="width: 0.1%">
            <v-btn style="cursor: move" icon class="sortHandle"><v-icon>drag_handle</v-icon></v-btn>
          </td>
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.sodium }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calcium }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS Prototype:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted () {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    new Sortable(
      this.$refs.sortableTable.$el.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
      {
        draggable: '.sortableRow',
        handle: '.sortHandle',
        onEnd: this.dragReorder
      }
    )
  },
  methods: {
    dragReorder ({oldIndex, newIndex}) {
      const movedItem = this.items.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]
      this.items.splice(newIndex, 0, movedItem)
    },
    itemKey (item) {
      if (!this.itemKeys.has(item)) this.itemKeys.set(item, ++this.currentItemKey)
      return this.itemKeys.get(item)
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      itemKeys: new WeakMap(),
      currentItemKey: 0,
      headers: [
        {
          sortable: false
        },
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Sodium (mg)', value: 'sodium', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Calcium (%)', value: 'calcium', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', sortable: false }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: '14%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: '6%',
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: '3%',
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: '7%',
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: '2%',
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: '12%',
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReKedj/

Comment: I fear your question way to vague to receive any answers. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Please edit your post accordingly - good luck

Comment: Thanks for the comments @5th. But i have just started to code.

Comment: As you told I have just made a prototype with the help of table data and table row but couldn't find out how to implement same in expansion panel with draggable.